# Handle file:// protocol in Ant script

Tags: ant, ivy, file-uri

Some Ant targets require an URL to be defined as property (like the `ivy pattern`) and since the `file://` protocol is different on Windows (either `file:/` or `file:///`) and Unix (`file://`) it makes the entire script less portable.

Is there a *nice* way to handle the `file` protocol without messing around with properties and Ant conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally decided to use the Condition task of Ant:

```
<condition property="file.protocol" value="file:///" else="file://">
    <os family="dos"/>
</condition>
```

Comment: I had a similar issue where I wanted to use file protocol follow by `${user.home}`. In windows that's: _C:\Users\Peter_ in unix: _/home/peter_. Because the unix user home already starts with **/**, I needed the condition prepend only 2 forward slashes for unix, and 3 for windows.  
`<condition property="user.home.file.proto" value="file://${user.home}" else="file:///${user.home}">
    <os family="unix"/>
</condition>`

Answer (score 1):

Using `file:///` should work on both systems. But perhaps the [PathConvert](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) task can help you out here?